# Download table with excel 2007

Tags: php, sql, export-to-excel

i have table result from query like this :

```
No l Agent l  Custumer
1     A          Devi
2     A          Lisa 
3     A          Dhea
4     B          Shinta
5     B          Wulan
6     B          Arthie
7     C          rIEKE
8     C          dONA
9     C          aNDHI
10    C          fHARA
```

I Want download the table by excel 2007 with design like this

```
No l Agent l  Custumer
1      A         Devi
2                Lisa
3                Dhea
4      B         Shinta
5                Wulan
6                Arthie
7      C         rIEKE
8                dONA
9                aNDHI
10               fHARA
```

how to coding php?

Comment: what have you tried in PHP ? also, you want download the file from browser in Excel format?

Comment: You could code this in PHP really easily - for each row, check to see if the value of Agent is the same as the currently stored value, if it is blank it out. And then set the currently stored value to the row's value. Voila, deduplicator.

Comment: end then how to code php?